# issue when importing BloomTokenizer from transformers in python

Tags: python, nlp, huggingface-transformers, huggingface-tokenizers, huggingface

I am trying to import BloomTokenizer from transformers

```
from transformers import BloomTokenizer
```

and I receive the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'BloomTokenizer' from 'transformers' 
(/root/miniforge3/envs/pytorch/lib/python3.8/site-packages/transformers/__init__.py)
```

my version of transformers:

```
transformers                 4.20.1
```

what could I do to be able to import BloomTokenizer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BLOOM has no slow tokenizer class. It only has a [fast tokenizer](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/model_doc/bloom#transformers.BloomTokenizerFast). The official documentation is wrong at this point. Use the following instead:

```py
 from transformers import BloomTokenizerFast
 tokenizer = BloomTokenizerFast.from_pretrained("...")
```